# tftp server configuration under ubuntu, Access violation

Tags: ubuntu, tftp

Here is my configuration:

```
$ vi /etc/xined.d/tftpd
service tftp
{
protocol        = udp
port            = 69
socket_type     = dgram
wait            = yes
user            = nobody
server          = /usr/sbin/in.tftpd
server_args     = /home/sliter/Server/tftpd
disable         = no
}
$ ls -l /home/sliter/Server/tftpd
drwxrwxrwx 2 nobody sliter 4096 2011-11-05 12:18 tftpd
```

Here is the problem:

```
$ ls -l 
-rwxrwxrwx 1 sliter sliter     0 2011-11-05 11:14 test
$ tftp localhost
tftp> put test
tftp> q
$ ls -l /home/sliter/Server/tftpd/test
-rw------- 1 nobody nogroup 0 2011-11-05 12:41 calc
$ cd ..
$ tftp localhost
tftp> get test
Error code 2: Access violation
```

- While it always shows this error message, the file is still downloaded.
- If I "$chmod 777 /home/sliter/Server/tftpd/test", the error message won't pop

I think the problem relates to file access, but I dont know how to fix this.

Thanks

Complements:

Well, as can be seen, the tftp server changed the uploaded file's permissions, owners, groups. I have to manually use chmod to avoid receiving the problem. So I just want to know is there some way fix this? or it is because I wrongly configured my tftp server?